# Totals not showing correctly in Power BI Table summing a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table summing **Meter Hrs**.  The total is incorrectly showing zero.  I need it sum all  **Meter Hrs** values:

[image]

**Meter Hrs** is a measure defined as the following:

```
Meter Hrs Total = 
        CALCULATE(MIN('Tenna Hours'[total_hours]),LASTDATE('Tenna Hours'[import_date]))
        - CALCULATE(MIN('Tenna Hours'[total_hours]),FIRSTDATE('Tenna Hours'[import_date]))
```

I thought this summing to zero, might be due to incorrect datatypes.  **[total_hours]** as a datatype of Decimal Number and **[import_date]** has a datatype of Date/Time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a `SUMMARIZE`d table:

```
Meter Hrs Total =
VAR MyTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE( 'Tenna Hours', 'Tenna Hours'[Equipment] ),
        "Meter Hrs",
            CALCULATE(
                MIN( 'Tenna Hours'[total_hours] ),
                LASTDATE( 'Tenna Hours'[import_date] )
            )
                - CALCULATE(
                    MIN( 'Tenna Hours'[total_hours] ),
                    FIRSTDATE( 'Tenna Hours'[import_date] )
                )
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        ISFILTERED( 'Tenna Hours'[Equipment] ),
        MINX( MyTable, [Meter Hrs] ),
        SUMX( MyTable, [Meter Hrs] )
    )
```

Comment: It works, but I don't think I understand why I needed a summarized table.

Comment: You made the mistake of assuming that the total row would **sum** the individual entries. But it doesn't - it applies the same aggregation as that used for the individual rows, though for all entries. Imagine you created a standard Pivot Table in Excel, and set the aggregation to average in the Values field. You would not expect the total row to perform a sum in that case, would you? No, you would expect it to perform an average, just as per the individual items, but for all items.